# Copy all elements of a array to another array at the specified index

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I want to copy all elements of an array to another at a specified location.

Eg:

```
Array A contains {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}

Array B contains {'x','y', 'z'}

Array C should now contain {'a', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'b', 'c', 'd'} when `insert-index`  is 1 (insert all B's at first index of A)
```

My preferred programming is in `Java` or in `C#`

**pseudo-code of my try:**

//Copy all the elements of the first array to the output array till the index
***//Copies 'a' to the output array***

```
for(int i=0;i<insert-index;i++)
output[i] = A[i]
```

//Copy all the elements of the destination array to the output array
***//copies 'x','y','z' to the output array***

```
for(int i=0;i<B.Array.Length;i++)
output[i] = B[i]
```

//copy all the elements of the source array to the output array.
***//copies remaining     'b', 'c', 'd'***

```
for(int i=0;i<A.Array.Length-index;i++)
output[i]=A[i]
```

The best shot at the algorithm I could give is `O(n power 3)`

Can any body tell me how else to approach or any pointers is greatly appreciated.

(EDIT: I know i could use `Array.Copy` or `memcpy` kind of internal functionality. But, I am just trying to learn how `did they do it` and also to improvise my prgm stuff.)

Comment: @downvoter: could you kindly point out the problem? I can correct it if its there.

Comment: @RomanVottner: I did not want to use the internal functionality. (kindly see the last lines of the question) I am trying to learn how did they do it? trying to improve the programming skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to think through what the starting and ending indices need to be.
I've included some comments below.

```java
// this part is straightforward
for (int i = 0; i < insert-index; i++)
  output[i] = A[i]

// we already have insert-index items in output, so continue from there
for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++)
  output[insert-index + i] = B[i]

// we already have (B.length + insert-index) items in output,
//   and we've already used insert-index items from A, so continue from there
for (int i = insert-index; i < A.length; i++)
  output[B.length + i] = A[i]
```

Since we're only touching each element of A and B once, it's `O(n)`. But it would probably be better to say it's `O(m + n)`, where `m` and `n` are the lengths of A and B respectively.

Comment: I was worried if the above algorithm is O(n power 3). No, only if it had three `for-loops` embedded then its a O(n power 3). Here, as you say, its o(n+m). Cool. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Array getCombination(int index, Array array1, Array array2)
{
  Array returnThis = new Array[array1.length + array2.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
  {
    returnThis[i] = array1[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
  {
    returnThis[i + index] = array2[i];     
  }

  for (int i = index; i < array1.length; i++)
  {
    returnThis[i + array2.length] = array1[i];
  }

  return returnThis;
}
```